# Como agregar un created en vue3?

Tags: vue.js

estoy utilizando un proyecto en vue 3.
En vue 2 se podría hacer un created() en el app.js como adjunto en la imágen. (no lo copio como script porque se ve distornicado el código)

Como podría montar el metodo created() en el main.js?
Como referencia es para guardar el token de un usuario logeado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de [Vuejs3](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html), ya no hace falta usar el método created para acceder a ese ciclo de vida de la instancia Vue. Simplemente debes hacer uso de la propiedad setup y esta, automáticamente, entrará dentro de lo que antes se conocía como el created y el beforeCreate. Ahora solo debes hacer algo como esto:

```
export default {
  props: {
    title: String
  },
  setup(props) {
    console.log(props.title)
  }
}
```

Al acceder a tu componente, te darás cuenta, que mostrará por consola el título de tu props pasado, sin necesidad de hacer uso de created.